# ¿Cómo proteger o limpiar el valor de mi atributo ACTION?

Tags: php

En muchos tutoriales sobre formularios con PHP recomiendan, por seguridad, al atributo **action** establecerle el siguiente valor:

```
 <form action="<?php echo 
 htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
```

Cuando tienes establecida la superglobal **$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]** en el **action** de un form, y en la url de la pagina donde se encuentra este form insertas código java script ( alert("por ejemplo") ), dicho código se ejecuta. Por esta razón recomiendan envolver la superglobal SERVER con el método **htmlspecialchars** (tal y como se ve en el codigo de arriba).

Cuando no incluyes la superglobal SERVER dentro del ACTION no se puede ejecturar ningun código java script en la URL. Por lo tanto quiero hacer dos consultas: La primera es ¿por qué debo usar la superglobal SERVER en mi ACTION si es que, al no utilizarla, evito que se pueda ingresa codigo java script ejecutable a través de la URL, y por ende evito usar el htmlspecialchars?.. Y la segunda es ¿de qué manera podría proteger mi formulario de ataques por la url?

Gracias.

Comment: No se que tutoriales has visto, pero no hay necesidad de escapar la url de un action que normalmente es hardcodeada, más aún si, el destino es la misma url del script lo puedes dejar en blanco. Lo que debes proteger son aquellos puntos donde recibes los valores de los usuarios o realizas alguna operación con datos externos...

Comment: Entiendo, gracias. Entonces significa que solo se debe escapar la URL del action si es que usas $_SERVER, de lo contrario, como en mi caso, no hay  necesidad de escapar nada (yo ni siquiera voy a poner el action ya que por defecto manda los datos al mismo sitio). Entonces solo me ocupare de validar que el contenido de los inputs no traiga caracteres extraños....Una cosa más: si decido enviar los datos a otro fichero , digamos action="otrofichero.php" ¿tampoco tengo de que preocuparme ? gracias